# Does saving an event to a CalCalendar just store a pointer to the CalEvent, instead of a copy?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, calendar

If I want to save the same kind of event to TWO calendars, it appears that I have to create two separate event objects, *is that correct*?

As an example, see the code below. An event gets saved to a calendar linked to a "worker", and then to a calendar linked to a "task".

```
- (BOOL)setTask:(MJSTask *)aTask
   fromDate:(NSDate *)from
     toDate:(NSDate *)to
{
    NSError *err = nil;
    CalEvent *e = [CalEvent event];
    NSString *task = [[aTask shortName] uppercaseString];
    // Set the first calendar
    [e setTitle:task];
    [e setIsAllDay:NO];
    [e setStartDate:[aTask start]];
    [e setEndDate:[aTask end]];
    [e setLocation:[self lastName]];
    [e setCalendar:[self calendar]];
    if ( ![[CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore] saveEvent:e span:CalSpanThisEvent error:&err] )
    {
       <error handling>
    }
    // Set the second calendar
    NSString *titleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)",[self lastName],task];
    [e setTitle:titleString];
    [e setLocation:[aTask longName]];
    [e setCalendar:[[aTask taskTemplate]calendar]];
    if ( ![[CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore] saveEvent:e span:CalSpanThisEvent error:&err] )
    {
        <error handling>
    }
    return FALSE;    
}
```

If I comment out the line where calendar 2 gets saved, I get the events in calendar 1. But If I don't, it seems that those objects only get saved to the last calendar (calendar 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. By saving twice, the second is effectively updating the event by moving it to a different calendar

Comment: Thanks, thought as much. I am surprised that the documentation does not state this clearly (or, perhaps, clearly enough for *me*!).